# Selecting one record from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm stuck with one SQL query. I have two tables:

1. users

   ```
   ________________________
   | id | company | worker|
   -------------------------
   | 1  | my comp | John  |
   ```
2. tasks

   ```
   _________________________
   | id | name | company   |
   -------------------------
   | 1  | exm  | my comp   |
   ```

My problem is that I want to show tasks of these companies which worker is John. I'm in trouble in that for hours but I don't know how to do it. Is there any SQL query to do that?

Comment: I see you added the join tag,so whats the problem?A little effort goes a long way.

Comment: Check out the MySql reference on [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Comment: You have an association between Companies and Workers in the USERS table, and an association between Names and Companies in the TASKS table, but no way I can see to tie a Task to a Worker. Are you asking for all the Tasks which belong to a Company which has a Worker named John?

Comment: Does anyone read manuals (where everything is described)? Use search http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple join using company column from both tables and use where clause to filter results for John

```
SELECT t.*
FROM users u
JOIN tasks t USING(company)
WHERE u.worker ='John'
```

Answer (score 0):

You want use the inner join tag. Just a modification on the other queries mentioned for better clarity.

```
SELECT task.name,user.worker,user.company 
FROM tasks as task INNER JOIN users as user 
 ON user.company=task.company 
 WHERE user.worker='John';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple join like...

```
$qry = "SELECT u.id,u.company,u.worker,t.id,t.name,t.company FROM users as u JOIN tasks as t ON u.company = t.company WHERE u.worker = 'John'";
```